# Хочу отправить запрос к сайту На Урок чтобы можно было получать ответы, но выдает ошибку. Можете с этим помочь?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Naurok Answers Table</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    button {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Naurok Answers Table</h1>
    <input type="text" id="linkInput" placeholder="Enter Naurok Link">
    <button onclick="getAnswers()">Get Answers</button>
    <table id="answersTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Answer ID</th>
                <th>Answer Text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="answersBody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="path/to/naurok-api-client.js"></script>

<script>
function getAnswers() {
    var link = document.getElementById('linkInput').value;

    // Виклик функції з API-клієнта для отримання відповідей
    var answers = NaurokApiClient.getAnswers(link);

    var tableBody = document.getElementById('answersBody');
    
    // Очищення таблиці перед виведенням нових даних
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';

    // Додавання даних у таблицю
    answers.forEach(function(answer) {
        var row = tableBody.insertRow();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        
        cell1.textContent = answer.id;
        cell2.textContent = answer.text;
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: NaurokApiClient is not definedhttps://36ab55aa-fb0e-43a6-84b4-6e1c7ab31f79-00-35l1gp30jyyza.riker.replit.dev/:6

Comment: Ошибка вам говорит, что переменная `NaurokApiClient` не определена. Я так понимаю, что она должна быть в **path/to/naurok-api-client.js**. Проверяйте. Прописные/заглавные буквы имеют значения

Comment: Может надо что-то добавить? Просто я новичок в этом деле.

Comment: Может. Для этого нужен код из скрипта naurok-api-client.js. А конкретно, нужен код `NaurokApiClient` - возможно это вообще класс